# How to groupby results from slick in playframework object?

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

this is Mycode:

```
case class Tabel1(id: Int, name: Option[String])
object Table1Table {
  class Table1Table(tag: Tag) extends Table[Tabel1](tag, "new_table") {    
    def id = column[Int]("id", O.AutoInc, O.PrimaryKey)
    def name = column[Option[String]]("new_table_col")    
    def * = (id, name) <> (Tabel1.tupled, Tabel1.unapply)
  }
  val tabel = TableQuery[Table1Table]
}    
val table2 = (for {
 (oX) <- Table1Table.tabel
} yield (oX))
.groupBy(?????); //group by
```

i have example data:

```
Tabel1(1,Some(new_table 1))
Tabel1(1,Some(new_table 5))
Tabel1(2,Some(new_table 2))
Tabel1(3,Some(new_table 3))
Tabel1(4,Some(new_table 4))
```

I want to result:

```
Tabel1(1,Some(new_table 1))// first or last
Tabel1(2,Some(new_table 2))
Tabel1(3,Some(new_table 3))
Tabel1(4,Some(new_table 4))
```

how to groupBy with result object name 'oX'?

Comment: What do you mean? Your table has two columns, id and name. If you want to group by id, you can do val groupedById = table2.groupBy(col => col.id), if you want to group by name, val groupedByName = table2.groupBy(col => col.name)

Comment: I would assume you are using something like: play-slick-evolutions? this is just to clarify your question. Also did you have a chance to play with slick examples http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.1/sql-to-slick.html#group-by ?

Comment: >>i have example data:
 
Tabel1(1,Some(new_table 1))
Tabel1(1,Some(new_table 5))
Tabel1(2,Some(new_table 2))
Tabel1(3,Some(new_table 3))
Tabel1(4,Some(new_table 4))


>>I want to result:
Tabel1(1,Some(new_table 1))// first or last
Tabel1(2,Some(new_table 2))
Tabel1(3,Some(new_table 3))
Tabel1(4,Some(new_table 4))

Comment: you marked the `id` as auto increment primary key, so you're not going to have multiple entries with same id.. that's why your question does not seem to make sense.